# Docker .bashrc service HTTP request fail

Tags: bash, docker

I wanted to run some services automatically in the startup, inside a docker container. SO I added the relevant commands to .bashrc in order to execute those services. And they are running as expected but one service which involved in sending HTTP requests to the localhost, fails to send the request to the server. But once I logged in to the docker container and execute the script manually through shell, it works properly. Looking forward your suggestions and answers.

Comment: can you show a reproducer?

Comment: This is my [Dockerfile](https://github.com/YasithLokuge/CobwebDocker/blob/master/Dockerfile)

Comment: Would that work better with `CMD ["bash", "-l"]` or `CMD ["-c", "bash", "-l"]`?

Comment: @VonC I tried your suggestion. But it didn't help me :(

Comment: @YasithLokuge can you try to add those same command in a `.profile` instead of `.bashrc`? (and still use `CMD ["bash", "-l"]`)

Comment: @VonC It didn't help either

Comment: Can you add some `echo "xxx"` in your `.bashrc` and `.profile` (the ones copied in your image) in order to see which one is sourced when you log in with `CMD ["bash", "-l"]`?

Comment: @VonC First it prints from the profile and then it prints from the bashrc

Comment: Ok, now what is the exact command that you put in (`.profile` or `.bashrc`) and which is not running?

Comment: @VonC Can you please check my [Dockerfile](https://github.com/YasithLokuge/CobwebDocker/blob/master/Dockerfile)

Comment: You CMD should be `CMD ["bash", "-l"]` (and put at the end of the dockerfile)

Comment: Then try `source ./coap` or `eval ./coap` instead of `sh ./coap`

Comment: @VonC Tried. Still the same issue. Not sending the request from .bashrc or .profile but works when logged in and manually executed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the service isn't completely started before the HTTP request hits it.  I would suggest adding either a delay between the two (`sleep 5` or so), or logic for performing some number of retries on initial connection failure.